# Phasing out monitor bleed

Tags: audio-recording, phase

I was just thinking, has anyone tried phase/polarity inverting to remove playback getting into a mic?

For example, recording a group vocal part and instead of giving them all headphones, just playing the accompaniment through a speaker and then removing it from the recording by adding an inverted signal of the track?

Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with "I don't know & I've never tried it."

Famously, Dave Stewart & Annie Lennox used to do her vocals on a hand-held SM58 in the control room with the phase of one monitor inverted, theoretically creating a null-space in the middle of the room.
All well & good, but I've actually seen video of her putting vox down & she doesn't stay anywhere near the centre of the room - so I'd call that 'hype'.

On the other hand, I've also recorded vox with a hand-held 58, in the control room *without* inverting the speaker phase.
It's not something I would have volunteered to do, but I needed the vocal performance on video at the same time, as an actual to-camera performance, so standard techniques were out.
U87 & cans were not on the menu.
Results were remarkably good. The 58's off-axis rejection, combined with the sheer proximity of the vocal compared to the monitors left me with a perfectly usable vocal & barely any spill at all.
The vocalist was free to move as he liked, & although didn't wander so far as Annie Lennox in the video I saw, it probably allows that her method worked for the same reasons.

So, hand-held 58s & you're good to go.

I'm not sure how far you'd get with an omni & everybody gathered round at a yard from the mic. A cardioid with its back to the monitor, maybe.

I think the idea of feeding an inverted signal into this is going to be fraught with difficulty. I don't think the frequencies will be time-aligned well enough to be able to get full cancellation. You are undoubtedly going to be picking up stray refections from the walls etc too.
You might get *some* joy if you can gradually rotate the phase to find a sweet spot, rather than merely flipping it 180° & I'd certainly say it would be worth a quick test - before the vocalists even get there - just in case it does work... but I wouldn't hold high hopes for it.

Comment: Hey thanks. I just had the idea pop into my head and wondered if anyone had tried it before and if it actually worked haha. If I end up testing it for fun I'll report back here.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head with the time delay and reflections. You may get a phase cancellation at 1 frequency (or multiple harmonic multiples of that frequency) but no - this is unlikely to work.